# Android Xamarin Forms getting lots of "No resource found that matches the given name" errors

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017 (latest)

[image]

I have tried almost everything to make it compile. No dice. The project compiles OK in another PC with the same VS version.

**EDIT:** I have added a link to the build output with the MSBuild debug level to "Diagnostic":  [Build.log](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AtXoQFW327DIw-M-SVFlLQF-Q7nViQ)

Comment: I've had this problem before. Make sure all your nuget packages are on the same version and clean rebuild.

Comment: Use menu tools: Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild project build output verbosity and log file verbosity->Diagnostic, you can see more detail information, If you still cant find useful information,  please include a full diagnostic build log.

Comment: I've added a link to the Build log. Please, look for the lines containing "error".